# DataView component list item in Sencha 2.3 using architect

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am trying to build a list in `sencha touch 2.3` (using sencha architect) by using `Ext.dataview.component.ListItem`. I was able to get the values from a store by using  `updateRecord` method , however I am not able to pass it back to main component.

This is what I am trying to achieve:-

I want to create a list of buttons whose text will be displayed dynamically from store and if user clicks it it should show the alert with age. I have a store with name and age in it. I  am able to get the name but I am not able to get the alert setup.I need help with that-
Here  is my **dataView** class

```
Ext.define('MyListItem.view.MyListItem', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.ListItem',
alias: 'widget.mylistitem',

requires: [
    'Ext.Button',
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],

config: {
    padding: 10,
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            handler: function(button, e) {
                var record = this.getRecord();
                console.log("buttonTapped");
                console.log(record);
                Ext.Msg.alert(
                record.get('name'), // the title of the alert
                "The age of this person is: " + record.get('age') // the message of the alert
                );
            },
            text: 'MyButton'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'component',
            flex: 1,
            html: 'Sample component inside dataitem'
        }
    ]
},

updateRecord: function(record) {
    // Provide an implementation to update this container's child items
    var me = this;
    me.down('button').setText(record.get('name'));
}

});
```

Here is my store:-

```
Ext.define('MyListItem.store.MyDirectStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'MyListItem.model.MyModel'
],

config: {
    data: [
        {
            name: 'Adam',
            age: '28'
        },
        {
            name: 'Eve',
            age: '27'
        }
    ],
    model: 'MyListItem.model.MyModel',
    storeId: 'MyDirectStore'
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you can't retrieve the record from the handler function like you're doing with `this.getRecord()`

You could update your button with the age too, then retrieve it to show the alert, something like:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    handler: function(button, e) {
        console.log("buttonTapped");
        Ext.Msg.alert(
            button.getText(), // the title of the alert
            "The age of this person is: " + button.getAge(); // the message of the alert
        );
    },
    text: 'MyButton',
    age: null
},
```

And:

```
updateRecord: function(record) {
    // Provide an implementation to update this container's child items
    var button = this.down('button');
    button.setText(record.get('name'));
    button.setAge(record.get('age'));
}
```

Even better it would be to store the info, or a reference to the record in a more appropriate place, like the `ListItem` itself maybe? But this should make it work.

Comment: @Anubis , Can you please have a look at my sencha touch problem described [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457136/sencha-touch-with-phonegap-using-sencha-cmd-and-phonegap-build-causes-error) ? Would be really grateful .